# how to check if a number is in octal in Haskell

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

I need a program that receives a String containing an octal number and converts it to decimal. If the String contains anything that's not a number from 0 to 8, the function should return a 0.

This is what I got:

```
octoDec :: [Char] -> Int
octoDec [] = 0
octoDec (x:xs) = ((digitToInt(x)) * 8 ^(length xs)) + octoDec xs
```

If I enter `octoDec ['1','2','3']`  I get `83` , which is expected.  However, how can I validate the user's without needing another function?

Edit: I've manage to build a function that checks if a number contains only digits between 0 and 7:

```
isOcto :: [Char] -> Bool
isOcto [] = True
isOcto (x:xs) | (digitToInt(x) > 0) && digitToInt(x) < 7 = isOcto (xs)
              |otherwise = False
```

what i wanted is to merge these two functions into one and return zero to invalid.

Comment: What do you mean by "needing another function"?  Needing to define another top-level function?  Needing to use another function?  Needing to define any other function at all?

Comment: I wanted the checking for octal to be made in the octoDec funtion

Comment: [Horner's Method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Horner%27s_method) is a more efficient way to compute the value. For an `n`-digit number, you only need O(n) multiplications instead of O(n) exponentiation operations.

Answer (score 2):

If you want `octoDec` to not only return the result, but also determine whether a result is even possible, return a `Maybe Int` instead of `Int`:

```
octoDec :: [Char] -> Maybe Int
octoDec [] = Just 0
octoDec (x:xs) = do
  rest <- octoDec xs
  let d = digitToInt x
  guard $ d >= 0 && d <= 7 
  pure $ rest + d * 8^length xs
```

The [`guard` function from `Control.Monad`](https://www.stackage.org/haddock/lts-18.16/base-4.14.3.0/Control-Monad.html#v:guard) will make the whole `do` block return `Nothing` if the condition doesn't hold.

Answer (score 0):

First, you'll want to use [Horner's Method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Horner%27s_method) to efficiently convert a sequence of digits to a single value.

```
> foldl (\acc n -> 8*acc + n) 0 (map digitToInt "123")
83
```

`map digitToInt` parses the string, and
`foldl (\acc n -> 8*acc + n) 0` is a function that evaluates the result of the parse.

```
horner :: [Int] -> Int
horner = foldl (\acc n -> 8*acc + n) 0

parseString :: [Char] -> [Int]
parseString = fmap digitToInt

octoDec :: [Char] -> Int
octoDec = horner . parseString
```

---

However, `digitToInt` isn't quite right: it can accept digits greater than 7,

```
> parseString "193"
[1,9,3]
```

and raises an exception for a value that isn't a digit at all.

```
> parseString "foo"
[15,*** Exception: Char.digitToInt: not a digit 'o'
```

We can write a better a function:

```
octalDigitToInt :: Char -> Maybe Int
octalDigitToInt c | c `elem` "01234567" = Just (digitToInt c)
                  | otherwise = Nothing
```

We can use that to convert an octal number into a sequence of digits, using `traverse` instead of `fmap`:

```
parseString' :: [Char] -> Maybe [Int]
parseString' = traverse octalDigitToInt
```

Valid octal string produce a `Just` value:

```
> parseString' "123"
Just [1,2,3]
```

while invalid strings produce a `Nothing` value:

```
> parseString' "193"
Nothing
> parseString' "foo"
Nothing
```

(Think of `traverse` as being a function that not only applies a function to a list of values, but only produces a list of results if each application succeeds. More precisely, it's a combination of `sequence` and `fmap`:

```
traverse f = sequence . fmap f
```

where `sequence` is the function that "inverts" a value of type `[Maybe Int]` to a value of type `Maybe [Int]`.)

---

With a more robust version of `parseString`, we need to adapt `octoDec` to handle the possibility that parsing will fail. We do that by using `fmap` to "lift" `horner` into the `Maybe` functor.

```
octoDec' :: [Char] -> Maybe Int
octoDec' s = fmap horner (parseString' s)  -- or octoDec = fmap horner . parseString'
```